# (Java) Converting 1x1 pixel to 3x3 pixel

Tags: java

Did an exercise whereby it wants me to write a program that reads a data file containing a number of 40,000 digits and using those digits, display an image in a graphics window of size 200x200.

Now the question asked me to replace the previous the 200x200 display with a 600x600 screen where each digit turns into a 3x3 pixel block.

```
//Setting the size of the graphics window
final int WINDOW_DIMENSION = 200;
EasyGraphics generate = new EasyGraphics(WINDOW_DIMENSION,WINDOW_DIMENSION);

//Constructing the arrays
    char[][] firstArray = new char[WINDOW_DIMENSION][WINDOW_DIMENSION];
    char[] secondArray = scan.toCharArray();

    //Using "for" loop to generate 2D array
    int line = WINDOW_DIMENSION;
    int column = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_DIMENSION*WINDOW_DIMENSION; i++) {
        column++;
        if (i%WINDOW_DIMENSION == 0) {
            line--;
            column = 0;
        }
        firstArray[column][line]=secondArray[i];
    }

    //Plotting the colours for respective range of numbers
    for (int a = 0; a < WINDOW_DIMENSION; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < WINDOW_DIMENSION; b++) {
            if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
                generate.setColor(66,167,243);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='4' || firstArray[a][b]=='5') {
                generate.setColor(0,255,77);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='6' || firstArray[a][b]=='7') {
                generate.setColor(51,183,91);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='8' || firstArray[a][b]=='9') {
                generate.setColor(102,51,0);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any solutions on how to work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information about what `generate` and `plot` are, one can only give the "generic" answer: Whatever `generate.plot(a,b)` is doing, it has to be done 3x3 times. So it should be sufficient to replace all calls to `generate.plot(a,b);` with

```
for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
        generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Replace each `generate.plot(a,b)` with the code above.

Before:

```
if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || 
    firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
    generate.setColor(66,167,243);
    generate.plot(a,b);
}
```

After:

```
if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || 
    firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
    generate.setColor(66,167,243);
    for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
        for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
            generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I fit this in my code? I'm sorry for asking this. I'm just not very familiar with arrays and loops @Marco13

Comment: Your code works, but what your code does is actually zooming into the image by 3 times instead of increasing the entire graphical window by a factor of 3. @Marco13

Comment: The question lacked important information (e.g. what this "EasyGraphics" class is and what it does). However, you have to adjust the window size. Based on the edited code in the qestion, this should probably be "... new EasyGraphics(WINDOW_DIMENSION*3,WINDOW_DIMENSION*3)"

Comment: The EasyGraphics is a package provided by my institution. it contains all the Java Graphics classes which are needed to produce a graphical output. Your code worked. For that, I'm truly grateful. @Marco13

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Setting the size of the graphics window
    final int WINDOW_DIMENSION = 200;
    EasyGraphics generate = new EasyGraphics(WINDOW_DIMENSION*3,WINDOW_DIMENSION*3);

    //Constructing the arrays
    char[][] firstArray = new char[WINDOW_DIMENSION][WINDOW_DIMENSION];
    char[] secondArray = scan.toCharArray();

    //Using "for" loop to generate 2D array
    int line = WINDOW_DIMENSION;
    int column = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_DIMENSION*WINDOW_DIMENSION; i++) {
        column++;
        if (i%WINDOW_DIMENSION == 0) {
            line--;
            column = 0;
        }

        firstArray[column][line]=secondArray[i];
    }

    //Plotting the colours for respective range of numbers
    for (int a = 0; a < WINDOW_DIMENSION; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < WINDOW_DIMENSION; b++) {
            if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
                generate.setColor(66,167,243);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='4' || firstArray[a][b]=='5') {
                generate.setColor(0,255,77);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='6' || firstArray[a][b]=='7') {
                generate.setColor(51,183,91);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='8' || firstArray[a][b]=='9') {
                generate.setColor(102,51,0);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```